# Extjs 4 Mozilla automatically add tooltip div

Tags: firefox, extjs, extjs4.1

I using Extjs 4 and Mozilla Firefox 48.0.2
In grid Mozilla automatically add tooltip div for cells which does not fit the contents in
How can i disabled this?

Comment: What does **Mozilla automatically add tooltip** mean. I checked in 48.0.2. Can you please but could'nt find any this kind of problem. Can you make a fiddle or put some code.

Comment: Yeah, this issue exist when any kind of label has **ellipsis**, so in this case MAC Safari automatically shows its own tooltip.But I didnt find this issue on any version of mozilla.It will be good if you share code in some fiddle.